Printing negative value as long with %ld in printf(3) results in an unsigned output, except with explicit type cast... Why?
Here are some tests I did
printf("%ld", -1); // output 4294967295 (UINT_MAX)
printf("%ld", (long) -1); // output -1

So why does it print  UINT_MAX instead of actual -1 without the type cast?
I expected both to print -1.

Doesn't your C compiler already print a warning about this (gcc -W -Wall)? If not, enable warning, or get a better C compiler.

This has little to do with it being negative. I'd expect a similar problem with 1.

@Barmar, 1 has a decent chance of "working" despite being UB as well. So while 1 suffers from the same problem, it might not as obvious.

One could avoid a cast by using -1L

The expression -1 (it's not a constant because of the unary -) has type int, and the %ld format specifier expects type long int.  The type mismatch means that your code has undefined behavior as per section 7.21.6.1p9 of the C standard regarding print format specifiers:

If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

What's probably happening (and there's no guarantee of this due to UB) is that printf is reading 4 bytes with all bits set and 4 more bytes with all bits set to 0.  Such a pattern when interpreted as a long int gives the result you're seeing.
The second line is fine because the cast is used to pass a parameter of the proper type.
